# И снова о годе

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Большое спасибо вам, что ответил на мой вопрос о "годе" и "лете".
Но у меня тут же возник новый - по поводу слов "погодить" и "погода". Родственны ли они слову "год"? И, если да, то "год" - это изначально некий абстрактный отрезок времени, который нужно подождать (погодить). Но как тогда быть с погодой? Или же здесь имеется в виду совокупность природных явлений, которые повторяются из года в год?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, конечно. "Год", как я уже писал, исходно означал "время", поэтому "погодить" - это просто обождать, потянуть (какое-то) время.

Вот что касается "погоды", то тут прямой этимологический ряд не просматривается, но надо учесть, что "погода" изначально относилось не просто к одномоментному состоянию атмосферы, а скорее к тому, что сейчас называют "сезонными показателями" (ср. "А какие у нас погоды стоят!"). Тогда все встает на свои места. Погода - *"**время**, когда что-то [характерное] происходит"*: особенно это касалось сбора урожая. Пересечение проискходит по значению "время".

Фасмер:

Этимология

Происходит от существительного год, далее от праслав. *godъ, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. годъ «время, срок», ст.-слав. годъ (греч. ὥρα, καιρός, χρόνος), русск. год, укр. годi «хватит, кончено», болг. годе́ в кой-годе «кто бы ни», сербохорв. го̑д (род. п. го̏да) «праздник», словенск. gȏd «пора, спелость, праздник, годовщина», чешск. hod «время, праздник», польск. gody мн. «празднество», в.-луж. hody мн. «рождество», н.-луж. gódy — то же.